# fstrim and iostat

Tags: io, ssd, trim

I have a new samsung ssd in my new notebook. I tuned up everything to avoid writings in the disk (firefox profiles and `/var/log` in memory), I'm using a `ext4` fs with `relatime` and I use `fstrim` once a day to TRIM my ssd.

I monitor disk load with `iostat -dhm`. Before running `fstrim` the command `iostat` shown

```
Device:            tps    MB_read/s    MB_wrtn/s    MB_read    MB_wrtn
sda
              4.97         0.05         0.59       1856      20924
```

after trimming `/home`

```
# fstrim -v /home
/home: 100.2 GiB (107555401728 bytes) trimmed
```

`ìostat` shows

```
Device:            tps    MB_read/s    MB_wrtn/s    MB_read    MB_wrtn
sda
              5.91         0.05         3.51       1859     123498
```

`MB_wrtn` increased `102574 MB`.
Does that mean `fstrim` is writing `102574 MB = 100.2 GB` to my disk ?

Trim is supposed to "mark" the pages that do not contain valid data, not writing them.

I guess `iostat` saw the operation made by `fstrim` as writing (even if *it is not* a writing). What do you think? Is there a better way to monitor my disk?

Note: Using `iotop` is not an answer, because it doesn't show the amount of data of processes that were killed. Thus, `iotop` measurement 
is inexact.

Comment: Uh, what? By definition, trimming is *not* writing bytes to the SSD. What's the problem?

Comment: the MB_wrtn counter shows 100 GB more. it seems fstrim wrote 100 GB

Comment: The message you posted says that `fstrim` *trimmed* 100GB.

Comment: Yeas, `fstrim` trimmed 100GB, but `ìostat` shows 100 GB being written

Comment: What does `strace fstrim` show?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Xyj63Yk3 this is the result of `strace fstrim`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> MB_wrtn increased 102574 MB. Does that mean fstrim is writing 102574 MB = 100.2 GB to my disk ?

Yes, it means exactly that. `fstrim` essentially looks at every single block of your block device and decides if the block is being used by the filesystem (that is, contains important data):

- block is in use: ignore it.
- block is not in use: send an ATA TRIM command for this block to the underlying block device.

When it's done, the amount of trimmed blocks should always be equivalent to the free space on the filesystem. `fstrim` TRIMs each free block every time you run it, regardless if it already has been TRIMmed in the past, so it won't become faster if you run it more often.

The kernel probably considers the TRIM command like a write command, so every executed TRIM command counts as a 4k write command.

> Trim is supposed to "mark" the pages that do not contain valid data, not writing them.

"Marking" blocks as trimmed is equivalent to "writing" them, because their contents change. If you'd accidentally TRIM the wrong block, you would lose data - just as writing zeros to the wrong block causes you to lose data.

Comment: Do you know a better way to monitor my disks? Some SSD manufacturers give lifespans like "5 years writing 8 GB daily". I'd like to monitor the amount of data being written to estimate the lifespan of my disk.

Comment: Use `smartctl -a /dev/sda | less`. There should be several indicators of wear, depending on the SSD brand.